# Setting up a virtual host on LAMP (Ubuntu 11) returns 403

Tags: apache-2.2, lamp

dear all, i am having problems with setting up a virtual host (Aptana Project directory) on a LAMP installation on ubuntu 11 (via tasksel).

i can access /var/www via ht*p://localhost, but accessing /home/tg/Aptana... via ht*p://ea-dev returns an "You don't have permission to access / on this server."

this is my apache2.conf: http://pastebin.com/Yja02tnE
this is my ea-dev located in /etc/apache2/sites-available/: http://pastebin.com/U1Vu2jxD

thats what i get in the error.log: [crit] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: /home/tg/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable

I really dont understand why its written /home/tg and not /home/tg/Aptana... but maybe its just an abbreviation.

also, when i restart apache, i get the following: 
[Fri Jun 03 15:58:19 2011] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts

Comment: and this is my default located in /etc/apache2/sites-available/: pastebin.com/Ayv9dPRk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If don't need to use any `.htaccess` file, try to change from

```
AllowOverride All
```

to

```
AllowOverride None
```

in the `<Directory>` section

Anyway, the `www-data` user needs read permissions in all directories in the path`'home/tg/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/ea-dev'`

This should help.

```
sudo chmod o+rx '/home'
sudo chmod o+rx '/home/tg'
sudo chmod o+rx '/home/tg/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace'
sudo chmod o+rx '/home/tg/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/ea-dev'
```

Comment: I need the .htaccess since it configures mod_rewrite. Anyway, your second suggestion worked, and the CakePHP configuration site now appears. Nonetheless it tells me now that /home/tg/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/ea-dev/app/tmp/cache/ and other directories are not writable. The owner and group of the files are all tg, and I do not understand whats the name of the Apache user that should actually access the files.. And what happens when I edit the files in Aptana?

Comment: @Timo May be, you had changed your `umask`? Check it executing `umask`, it should be `0022`. A quick workaround: `sudo chmod -R o+rx '/home/tg/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/ea-dev'`.

Comment: Yes, umask equals 0022, but executing recursive chmod does not change anything. The directories are still not writable. I think I lack understanding of users and groups in this case. I mean, tg, thats me. But I do not know what user actually access the file when somebody browses the files in the browser. Is it www-data and if yes, should I add tg to the www-data group or www-data to the tg group? :) See I am kinda confused here. After all I need to know whether a certain user, group or others need write access.

Comment: Apache in ubuntu runs as `www-data` user, and all PHP is executed under this user either. Usually PHP only needs to read files, but some frameworks like CakePHP write in some places like temporary folders, or cache folders. Try to add write permissions to the temporary folder (and following folders CakePHP complains): `chmod -R o+w '/home/tg/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/ea-dev/app/tmp'`

Comment: So I need to change all those files' owner to www-data or can I leave it to tg and just consider www-data as "others"?

Comment: Sorry @Timo, you saw unfinished comment, read it again. It's better to consider www-data as "others"

Comment: Ok- I read that on another place too. Now, its kinda clear to me. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

you need to link your vhost to sites-enabled

or just use: a2ensite yourVhostFile